# Lua: Proper Scoping with Buffer Manipulation

Tags: lua, scope, buffer

I'm trying to create a buffer that is built with an input.  This buffer would then send the captured strings to another function in the file that would manipulate the strings and utilize it later in other function(s).  The first capture is parsed as expected and is fine.  I'm having an issue clearing the buffer for new string captures when new data is received.  Instead, it is adding the new strings onto the original ones, leaving me unable to properly manipulate it.  Here is an example of what I'm trying to do:

```
local buffer = ""

function action(input)
    buffer = buffer..input
    parse_data(buffer)
end  

function parse_data(data)
     obj = ""
     obj_var = buffer:match("(%d).*")
     if obj_var == 1 then
         obj = do_some_function()
     else
         obj = do_some_other_function()
     end
     buffer = ""
end

function do_some_function()
     some action
end

function do_some_other_function()
     some chunk
end
```

I do not know where to plug a command or function to clear the file's `buffer` variable prior to each new send.  I know that this is very very simplistic code.  But I hope I conveyed what I'm trying to get done with the buffer variable.  This is a plugin file that will receive the input at it's main function to build each buffer.  Then depending on the input, it will report to that specific function. I've tried to place `buffer = ""` at the end of each function and no go.  I've also tried to change the variable call in `function string(buffer)` to another variable but that still doesn't clear the buffer.  I guess I'm more so getting confused as to the lexical scoping of the buffer and how it would be best to clear it.

Thanks for all the help.

Comment: Unrelated but `string` is a bad name for a function as it will hide the default `string` table.

Comment: When, flow wise, should the buffer be cleared? Is there an event that should trigger that? Is there a certain input that means "clear buffer and start again"?

Comment: @EtanReisner In response to your question, the only event would be when new data is sent down.  Ideally, I think (from my limited programming experience) it would be best if the successful operation of the `function string(buffer)`, which I won't do again, would clear the buffer for new input.  But as I mentioned, entering `buffer = ""` in the chunks of the if then statement or at the end of the function itself will not clear it.

Comment: The function argument `buffer` is an implicit local and is shadowing the outer local of the same name. Use a different function argument name and `buffer = ""` will work.

Comment: You can update your main post with the modified functions if they still aren't working.

Comment: Why are you maintaining a buffer if you want to clear it immediately? why not just pass `input` to your `string` function (you should really change the name) directly instead and then not have to deal with this? Or is this code over-simplified? As written the code looks like it should work (though the `data = buffer` bit isn't at all necessary).

Comment: The code appears to clear buffer: https://eval.in/282690

Comment: Changed the code to reflect discussion.  Input comes in pieces followed by CR & LF's, but they are stripped out by the parent program running the plugin.  I'm trying to take those pieces into a buffer and use that as a means to manipulate all of the data sent down.  Once the buffer resembles the specific format, it then sends the data to the corresponding function.

Comment: @EtanReisner thanks for your help.  It must be an issue with my equipment here.  I'm placing `print` commands in certain spaces and I do see that it is clearing it.  But for some reason it is still adding the strings together and maintaining it in the system.  Almost as if it is clearing it from the one function but not the other inside the system.  Thank you Etan.  I want to give you credit for your help.  Please post this as an answer so I can.

Comment: What environment is this in? Is this stock lua or something custom? This almost sounds like a custom lua that uses 'local-by-default' or something horrible like that.

Comment: @EtanReisner Equipment is based on Linux.  System built with C++ utilizing Lua for custom work.